# how to fix Doctrine\DBAL issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue when I run php artisan migrate in laravel

[TypeError]   Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ensureForwardCompatibilityStatement() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement, instance of PDOStatement given

Comment: Which environment do you run in?

Comment: on Mac using Xamp 7.2.34 
Laravel 5.2

Comment: You are describing too little information so I cannot help. Is your application completely new or modified?

Comment: Pls give full  error log

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ensureForwardCompatibilityStatement() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement, instance of PDOStatement given, called in /Users/jmeelahmed/Projects/glfrontend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 1313

Comment: its modified project. it was working perfect but suddenly it stopped working dont know what the reason is

Comment: [TypeError]                                                                                                                                                                                            
  Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ensureForwardCompatibilityStatement() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement, instance of PDOStatement given, called in /Users/ja  
  meelahmed/Projects/glfrontend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 1313

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231112/discussion-between-chung-nguyn-trn-and-jameel-ahmed-ansari).

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, check the value of `DB_PDO_PERSISTENT` in your `.env` file:
The error you mention will come up (as of `doctrine/dbal`:`2.13.2`) if the connection is persistent.

This will result in an error above:

```
DB_PDO_PERSISTENT=true
```

And this will be fine:

```
DB_PDO_PERSISTENT=false
```

PS: If you have to change it, don't forget to `php artisan config:clear`